# Postgres Replication Tools for DDL

Tags: postgresql, replication

Is there any tools for replication in postgres which can doing the following :

1. automatic DDL replication?
2. when master DB down, then slave will become the master DB immediately.
3. my company database is +- 5GB size

i have search some tools for replication which is slony and bucardo (and all trigger based replication system cannot doing the DDL replication)([source](http://scanningpages.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/9-0-streaming-replication-vs-slony/)). and for 9.0 Streaming Replication (built in on postgres),[Gabriel Weinberg](http://www.gabrielweinberg.com/blog/2011/05/replicating-postgresql-with-bucardo.html) ([DuckDuckGo](http://DuckDuckGo.com))said "Steve Signer [wrote up](http://scanningpages.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/9-0-streaming-replication-vs-slony/) some cases where you wouldn't want to/be able to use the built-in replication"

so 3 tools i found (slony,bucardo and 9.0 SR) , doesnt meet my criteria to do the postgres. is there any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: Why do you think streaming replication does not do what you want?

Comment: i want to replicate some of db to the slave. not all of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. automatic DDL replication?

=> Use streaming replication, replicates everything.

1. when master DB down, then slave will become the master DB immediately.

=> [pgPool](http://www.pgpool.net/pgpool-web/contrib_docs/simple_sr_setting_3.1/index.html) does it's job over here, works fine.

1. my company database is +- 5GB size

=> That's very small, don't worry.

Comment: hi frank, thanks for your answer. i wanna ask for streaming replication, can i replicate some of database on postgres and only certain table inside that db? for pgPool, i will explore more about it

Comment: No, streaming replication can only replicate everything. If you want specific tables, check Slony. But Slony can't replicate DDL.

Comment: so i wouldnt use both neither :). but i still exploring pgpool.. thanks frank

Answer (score 0):

You can use [debezium](https://debezium.io/) for replication transactions (insert, delete and update)... for ddl you can use kafka connect ;)